# Copying the values from a DataGrid to an Array vb6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

i have a problem that i want to resolve.

I want to check if a column have a value repeated in the rows of a datagrid, before the adodc update the records in the database.

For doing that i'm gonna get the records that are showed in the DataGrid and put them in an Array, then count the quantity of rows with the same value in the cell.

The problem i have is that i can't put the cells of the DataGrid in an array so i can do the check of the repeated rows.

How can i get the Cells of the DataGrid in an Array?
Or how can i know if the value of a row is repeated before making the update in the database?

Comment: Normally you catch attempted duplicates by using constraints at the database. The DataGrid and other bound controls are designed to report constraint violations back to you via mechanisms like the DataGrid's Error event. The DataGrid isn't meant to be used with a lot of procedural logic in an unbound mode.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @bob-riemersma that your validation should be done via databinding and db constraints, but if you want to do it manually (and I think this is a bad idea), I would use a collection:

```
Private Function GridColHasDuplicates(col As Long) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo DupeError
    Dim noDupes As New Collection

    myGrid.row = 0
    myGrid.col = col
    Do While myGrid.row <= myGrid.VisibleRows - 1
        noDupes.Add myGrid.Columns(col).Value ' this will error off if dupe
        If myGrid.row < myGrid.VisibleRows - 1 Then
            myGrid.row = myGrid.row + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    GridColHasDuplicates = False
    Exit Function
DupeError:
    GridColHasDuplicates = True

End Function
```